# how to write IS NOT for str.endswith in python

Tags: python

How to write something like `!(str.endswith())` in python
I mean I want to check if string IS NOT ending with something.
My code is

```
if text == text. upper():   and text.endswith("."):
```

But I want to put IS NOT after and
writing

```
if text == text. upper():   and not text.endswith("."):
```

or

```
if text == text. upper():   and not(text.endswith(".")):
```

gives me **Invalid syntax**

Comment: Did you try `not "foo".endswith("bar")`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have an extra colon:

```
if text == text. upper():   and not text.endswith("."):
#                       ^
```

Remove it and your code should work fine:

```
if text == text.upper() and not text.endswith("."):
```

Comment: remove last string, without text== if is not checking text

Answer (score 4):

You can use `not`

```
if not str.endswith():
```

your code can be modified to:

```
if text == text.upper() and not text.endswith("."):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `not()` oporator:

```
not(str.endswith())
```

EDIT:
Like so:

```
if text == text. upper() and not(text.endswith(".")):
    do stuff
```

or

```
if text == text. upper() and not(text.endswith(".")):
   do studff
```

Comment: `not` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: Ah, so it is.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: invalid syntax guys :(

Comment: what do you mean just ?

Comment: hmm, not in python2.7.3  Which version are you using?

Comment: I need both conditions to be checked in that IF

Comment: dunno got canopy Version: 1.1.0 (64 bit)

Comment: your problem is the extra semicolon.

Comment: yep thanks, just saw that in iCodez answer, also marked your answer as usefeull. thanks for the help

Comment: I was surprised to see that one can use `not` like a function... I always say `not text.endswith('.')` rather than `not(text.endswith('.'))`. After all, hey, it's python, the less the clutter, the better :)